# How should I set database fields for a Radio Program Schedule table and how to retrieve data?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-design

I'm working on a radio web site project based on Codeigniter.

Here is layout of the schedule:
http://postimage.org/image/nb68dfr9t/

Now, I have a progamme table. There are programme_id, programme_title, programme_content, programme_day, programme_time fields inside it.

If one programme was supposed to be on-air only 1 day of the week, I wouldn't be in any trouble. I could easily set programme_day field to pass as a variable at Codeigniter (such like day/show/monday).

But situation is much more complicated.

One radio programme can be at only 1 day of the week, it can be at week days, it can be at weekends or it can even be at let's say monday, wednesday and friday...

So how should I set my database fields in this case? Only one field called "Programme_day" wouldn't be enough, I think?

What is the best practise for this?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** If you want to see everything once, have a Monday, a Tuesday, etc. column., each boolean (if every day they run on the same time). Simple to retrieve data even if this looks complicated.

**2.** If you want the simplest solution, I say you should add the programme for every day. It's still simple to retrieve data.

**3.** If you REALLY want to make it need the least space possible, assign 1 to Monday, 2 to Tuesday, 4 to Wednesday, etc., then select which days does it run in and add them and that'll be the day value. If you use this, then it is hard to retrieve data. This is a variation of solution 1.

**4.** If you want a bit less space then Solution 2 requires, add a table for containing all details except time and one containing only days and times (and ID of course).

In my opinion, I'd go for **solution 2**, that makes possible to schedule programmes on different times every day and needs no changes. Or if you want less space to be used, you could try **solution 4**. Solution 1 has some advantages as well, but that has less functionality then 2 and 4. Solution 3 has the same problems as Solution 1, but it's overly complicated (but needs less columns so a bit less complicated in structure). But I still say **solution 2** or **solution 4** work the best.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain "Solution 4" a little more?

Comment: Have a table `programme_details` with `programme_id, programme_title, programme_content` and a table `programme_times` with `programme_id, programme_day, programme_time`. programme_times contains the programme more times (so programme_id is NOT unique), every time when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a programme table, then a programme schedule table that takes the programme PK and have the date/time when it is aired. So you would have a 1:N relationship

Answer (score 0):

You should create another table for program schedule where you maintain program schedule. Table structure something like program_id, program_day, program_time. So you can easily manage the records.

Answer (score 0):

maybe look like this http://radio.cvmiladiyyah.web.id/jadwal

i ever take project radio.